# Calculate number of days between two days

Tags: jquery

I am trying to calculate number of days from two selected dates,My code is not working.Is there any mistakes?

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
            calulateDays()
    });

    function calulateDays(){
        $('#levTo').blur(function(){
var levfrom=$('#levFrom').val();
    levto=$('#levTo').val();
    from, to,duration;

from = moment(levfrom, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
to = moment(levto,'YYYY-MM-DD');
duration=to.diff(from,'days')    
$('#levDuration').val(duration + ' days');

});
}
```

```html
          
   <label>Date From</label>
   <input type="date" name="levFrom" id="levFrom" class="levFrom">
       
   <label >Date To</label>
   <input type="date" name="levTo"  id="levTo" class="levTo">
   
   <label >Duration</label>
   <input type="text" name="levDuration" id="levDuration" class="levDuration" readonly="readonly">
```

Comment: You are missing reference to moment.js-library which you seem to be using. Add that to your page.

Comment: Yes I added that plug-in `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this bro

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            calulateDays()
        
    });

    function calulateDays(){
        //$('#levTo').on('keyup mouseup change',function(){
        $('#levTo').on('change',function(){
        var levfrom=$('#levFrom').val();
        var levto=$('#levTo').val();
        var from,to,duration;
    
        from=moment(levfrom, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
        to=moment(levto,'YYYY-MM-DD');
        duration=to.diff(from,'days');
        $('#levDuration').val(duration + ' days')
    
    });};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<label>Date From</label>
   <input type="date" name="levFrom" id="levFrom" class="levFrom">
       
   <label >Date To</label>
   <input type="date" name="levTo"  id="levTo" class="levTo">
   
   <label >Duration</label>
   <input type="text" name="levDuration" id="levDuration" class="levDuration" readonly="readonly">
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `calulateDays` function is missing `}`. Also, js is case sensitive. So, you must be using `levfrom` and `levto` with lowercase `f` and `t` when you are accessing them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        calulateDays()
});

function calulateDays(){
    $('#levTo').on('keyup mouseup change',function(){
    var levfrom=$('#levFrom').val();
        levto=$('#levTo').val();
        from,to,duration;

    from=moment(levFrom, 'YYYY-MM-DD');   // HERE: levfrom
    to=moment(levTo,'YYYY-MM-DD');        // HERE: levto
    duration=to.diff(from,'days')    
    $('#levDuration').val(duration + ' days')

  });
}  // <==== HERE
```

Also, consider improving your js code:

```
  $(document).ready(calulateDays);

  function calulateDays() {
    $('#levTo').on('keyup mouseup change', function () {
      var levfrom = $('#levFrom').val(),
        levto = $('#levTo').val(),
        from, to, duration;

      from = moment(levfrom, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
      to = moment(levto, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
      duration = to.diff(from, 'days')
      $('#levDuration').val(duration + ' days')
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    function calulateDays(){
        var levfromArr=$('#levFrom').val().split('-'),               levtoArr=$('#levTo').val().split('-');
        var leavefromDay=levfromArr.pop();
        var levfromMonth=levfromArr.pop();
        var levfromYear=levfromArr.pop();
        
        var levtoDay=levtoArr.pop();
        var levtoMonth=levtoArr.pop();
        var levtoYear=levtoArr.pop();
        
        var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; 
        var firstDate = new Date(levfromYear,levfromMonth,leavefromDay);
        var secondDate = new Date(levtoYear,levtoMonth,levtoDay);

        var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() -           secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
         
        $('#levDuration').val(diffDays + ' days')
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Date From</label>
   <input type="date" name="levFrom" id="levFrom" class="levFrom">
       
   <label >Date To</label>
   <input type="date" name="levTo"  id="levTo" class="levTo">
   
   <button onclick="calulateDays()"  >Duration</button>
   <input type="text" name="levDuration" id="levDuration" class="levDuration" readonly="readonly">
```

Try this out. its working snippet

Comment: thanks.Can I do this using `.blur()` ?And wats wrong in my code?

Comment: Yes you can use this function with any of the valid event. My function is independunt from your function a i used pure jQuery and JS code instade of moment.js. you might have initialization issue in your code.

Comment: Issue with your code is importing librery. u might not import moment.js or jquery script which you use in ur code.